# How do I get a value from a column comprising of multiple values separated by semicolon in teradata

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, teradata

I have a column as mentioned below and I need to get the value of "cg" from it using teradata sql:

```
cat=0;cg=dbeca43414a0a5f16431a3e1ff446252;eb_trk=5
cat=20349;cat=15032;cat=9394;cg=578b0f761490a5f164
cat=9355;cat=15032;cg=975f70b714d0a2b143a56055fbfd
cat=42428;cat=15032;cg=bceb58e114a0a5f165405b20f7f
cat=9355;cat=15032;cg=d93dfc1714c0a5616b212801fd73
```

Comment: Can you suggest the regexp_subtr? And what if cg= is not present in the column?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `regexp_substr()` in Teradata is essentially the same as the same function in Oracle.  The following should work:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(col, 'cg=[^;]+', 1, 1), '[^=]+', 1, 2)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1698) is a SQL Fiddle with the Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

TD14+ supports a name-value-pair function (besides REGEXP_SUBSTR):

```
NVP(col,'cg',';','=')
```